# Allow a period in an item name for a specific template

Tags: item-name

We are working on a system where government regulation information is being captured as items in Sitecore. Since the regs have periods in the numbers (IE FAR 1.103-3), we want to use the real regulation name in the item name. However, the period is a disallowed character. I checked the `InvalidItemNameChars` setting and I don't even see the period in there as a disallowed character, so I'm guessing it's something in the `ItemNameValidation` setting regular expression. And I don't want to allow a period everywhere for item names, just a specific template.

Is there a way to create an item naming convention override for a specific template? I know we could use the display name, but authors by default are going to want to type in the period and not some other characters, like an underscore, to make it work. Before I lock in on the display name route, I wanted to check if an override is possible.

Comment: What benefit will you get by allowing the period? Perhaps you can just update the Display name with the period?

Comment: Do you think it would meet your needs to have a processor run on Save to change the period to something else for the author, but keep the period in the Display Name? That way the author would get the 'easy entry' but the system could keep it's rules.

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr Yeah, I was thinking about that, if there was a way for them to enter the period, but it creates the item name with a legal name (like 1_103-3) but the display name keeps the original. It's getting past the big "you can't use that character" message you get when you go to add a new item in the content editor.